# Unknown command error with labelmap command in lammps

Tags: label, lammps

I am writing a very basic lammps script for simulation of lennard-jones fluid. The code I used is the following:

```
# Molecular Dynamics Simulation of a Lennard-Jones gas in 2D

# Initialization of Boundary

dimension   2
boundary    p p p


# Units and Atomic information

units       lj
atom_style  atomic


# Simulation box setup and atom initialization

region      box block 0 100 0 100 -5 5
create_box  1 box
create_atoms    1 random 100 345423 box
mass        1 2.0
labelmap        clear
labelmap    atom 1 gas-mol


# Potential definition

pair_style  lj/cut 3
pair_coeff  1 1 1.0 1.0 2.5


# Velocity initialisation

velocity    all create 1.0 25648


# Output Specifications

thermo      100
thermo_style    custom step temp press etotal


# Simulation settings

neighbor    0.3 bin
neigh_modify    delay 5
fix     box all nve
timestep    0.003
#dump       dynamics all movie 30 movie.mpg type type size 640 480 


# Run
run 1000
```

However, the output shows up an error:

> ERROR: Unknown command: labelmap  clear (src/input.cpp:279)

I am not sure what is going wrong, and there is no unknown command error message in the lammps documentation as well. I tried checking the release pages of the newest version, but couldn't find anything on why this is the case. Any help is much appreciated.